# Local minimum of the function:

Tags: calculus, functions, optimization, proof-verification, calculus-of-variations

Find the local minimum of the function:
$$\def\f{f(x_1,x_2,x_3)}\def\1{x_1}\def\2{x_2}\def\3{x_3}\def\n{\nabla}$$
$$\f=\1^2-2\1\2+2\2^2+\3^2 \text{ in } \mathbb{R}^3$$

---

$\n\f=(2\1-2\2,-2\1+4\2,2\3) = \vec{0}$
Hence $\3=0$, and $\1=\2$, but $2\1=4\2$, hence $\1=\2=\3=0$

And the critical point is $(0,0,0)$ at $\f$ is $f(0,0,0)=0$.

Taking the Hessian matrix I can see that $\det(H(\1,\2,\3))=8$ and $f_{XX}=2$. Since these are both $\gt0$, this is a minimum.

Is this correct?

Comment: Looks good. Now one only needs to verify that it is a (local) minimum.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_partial_derivative_test

Comment: @Lemon Thank you lemon, added in. Is the logic behind this test easy to learn? OR should I wait until I build more Mathematical maturity?

Comment: That's an easy argument, if you know the Taylor expansion, you may see that $f(x)=f(x_0)+f'(x_0)(x-x_0)+(x-x_0)^t f''(x_0)(x-x_0) + o(|x|^3)$ in multi variable, $f''$ is the Hessian. If $f''(x_0)$ is positive definite, then $(x-x_0)^t f''(x_0)(x-x_0)>0$. This is an easy argument that you may see in any book about multivariable calculus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$f(x_1 , x_2 , x_3 ) =(x_1 -x_2 )^2 +x_2^2 +x_3^2 $$
hence $$\min_{(x_1 ,x_2 ,x_3 )\in\mathbb{R}^3 } f(x_1 , x_2 , x_3 ) =f(0,0,0) =0$$